# Nested Con statement arcpy

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, con

I am trying to combine three conditions into one con statement line:

```
ndvi_adjusted = Raster(ndvi_raw) * 0.004 - 0.08
con1 = Con(Raster(ndvi_adjusted) >= 0, ndvi_adjusted)
con2 = Con(IsNull(con1), 0, con1)
```

I am quite confused with the where clause input and map algebra expressions in Con. I tried some ways to aggregate the three lines into one but did not work out. How can Con statement be properly aggregated?

Comment: Con(isnull(raw),0, Con(raw>20, raw*0.004-0.08, 0))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More logical solution in your case

```
Con(isnull(raw) or (raw<20), 0, formulae)
```

Use symbol from raster calculator for OR, I cannot find one on my phone

Formulae is .004*raw-0.08 which is negative at raw < 20

Comment: Did answer above solved your original question? Obviously yes, because you removed your comments. Rules here say: one Q per post, mark as solved, post a new one